# How to compose ecto queries with join

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have three models `User`, `Group`, `UserMembership`.

Relationship among them is

```
defmodule Samajika.Group do
  has_many :user_memberships, MyApp.UserMembership
  has_many :users, through: [:user_memberships, :user]
end
```

`UserMembership` model has a `type` column that stores the type of membership. For eg., it might store `owner`, `tenant` etc.

Now I want to query `Group` and get its members who are only tenants.

```
Ecto.assoc(group, :users) |> Repo.all
```

The above gives me all users. The query looks like this

```
#Ecto.Query<from u0 in Samajika.User, join: u1 in Samajika.UserMembership,
 on: u1.group_id in ^[1], where: u0.id == u1.user_id, distinct: true>
```

I want to use Ecto query composition to add where clause with `type` on `user_memberships` table.

I have added this code in my group

```
def tenant(query) do
    from c in query, where: c.type == "tenant"
end
```

and I do this

```
Ecto.assoc(group, :users) |> Group.tenant
```

however this adds `where` clause on the `users` table, rather than join table `user_memberships`

What should I modify in my `tenant` function to add the condition on the join table?

Answer (score 11):

Pass a list to `in` in the `from` call:

```
def tenant(query) do
  from [_u, c] in query, where: c.type == "tenant"
end
```

The first argument would be the main table and second would be the first join.

Comment: This requires any query to be dependent on the main query.  Not idea for abstraction and reusability.